# Error: Element at index 0 is not a valid DocumentReference

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to retrieve all the blogs to whom user is subscribing/following like Instagram. I'm using Firebase Cloud Functions and Firestore.

```js
exports.currentUserSubscriberPost = (req, res) => {
  const subscriberDoc = db
    .collection("subscriber")
    .where("userHandle", "==", req.user.handle);
  let subscribing = [];
  const BlogsDoc = db.collection("blogs");
  subscriberDoc
    .get()
    .then(async doc => {
      doc.forEach(data => {
        subscribing.push({ subscribingUserId: data.data().userId });
      });
      if (subscribing.length > 0) {
        let ref = subscribing.map((user) => db.collection('blogs').where('userId','==',user.subscribingUserId));

        let blogsData = await db.getAll(...ref);
        return blogsData;
      } else {
        return res.json({ msg: "you are not subscribing to anyOne" });
      }
    })
    .then(data => {
      let blogs = [];
      data.forEach(data => {
        blogs.push( data.data() );
      });
      return res.json(blogs);
    }).catch(err => console.error(err))
};
```

Comment: Its a bit hard to tell since you didn't say what line the error occured on, but I'm suspicious of the `db.getAll` call.  [It takes DocumentReferences](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.19.x/Firestore#getAll) but you passed it a set of [Querys](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#where).

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve the Query objects you are obtaining using the `where` method. You should iterate through the queries and [`get`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.19.x/Query#get) the actual DocumentReference objects that you need to call `getAll()`